# Open popup for microphone permission using javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to open permission popup for microphone if microphone permission is not granted,

```
navigator.permissions.query(
        { name: 'microphone' }
    ).then(permissionStatus => {
        
        console.log(permissionStatus.state); // granted, denied, prompt
        if(permissionStatus.state != 'granted')
        {  
          alert('Please allow your microphone');
        }
        else
        {
          this.mic_permission=true;
        }
        let self=this;
        permissionStatus.onchange = function(){
          if(this.state!='granted')
          {
            self.mic_permission=false;
          }
          console.log("Permission changed to " + this.state);
        }
```

using this code to check whether microphone permission is granted or not but i want to open popup also so that user can allow the microphone permission

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to change the permission through javascript. I think you have to direct the user to the browser setting where they have to change it themselves.

Comment: @Kokodoko: I don't want to change the setting through javascript, i want to open that permission pop up only user can change the settings

Comment: There is no direct way to open that permissions window. It usually opens automatically when you try to do something that needs a permission. (as far as I know).

Comment: @Kokodoko: Okay Thanks

Comment: After a user has made its choice, you're not able to create another prompt. You'll have to instruct the user to manually change the permission setting.